# Can't retrieve params from rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've got this form tag from which I want to retrieve a starting date and end date (dd/mm/yy):

```
<%= form_with(url: "dashboard/index", method: "get") do %>
  <%= date_select :start_date, :date_att %>
  <%= date_select :end_date, :date_att %>
  <%= submit_tag("Apply") %>
<% end %>
```

This is what I'm doing in my controller once the 'Apply' button has been pushed:

```
start_f = params[:start_date]
```

which I expect to give me `{"date_att(1i)"=>"2019", "date_att(2i)"=>"10", "date_att(3i)"=>"31"}` but instead I get `<ActionController::Parameters {"date_att(1i)"=>"2019", "date_att(2i)"=>"10", "date_att(3i)"=>"31"} permitted: false>`

I tried looking for ways to make the *permitted* attribute TRUE but I don't understand.

Can anyone help me on this one ?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), sth like:

```
start_f = params.permit(:start_date)[:start_date]
```

Comment: I get something new, but it doesn't work. "Unpermitted parameters: :start_date, :end_date, :commit". I saw ".permit!" function, is that of any use here ?